# S.redirectTo() not working in scala liftweb

Tags: lift

I have following code in a snippet SignInController as follows that should redirect to a new view. But it only shows **"The Requested URL /home was not found on this server"**

```
import code.model.User

import net.liftweb.mapper.By
import net.liftweb.common.Loggable
import scala.xml.NodeSeq
import net.liftweb.common.Full
import net.liftweb.http.S
import net.liftweb.util.PassThru
import net.liftweb._
import http._
import util.Helpers._

object SignInController{

  def render = {
    var username = ""
    var password=""
     def process() {
      val userList: List[User] = User.findAll(By(User.username, username))
      for( u <-  userList )
      {
        if(u.password.equals(password))
        {
          S.redirectTo("/home")
        }
      }

    }
    "name=username" #> SHtml.text(username, username = _) &
      "name=password" #> SHtml.password(password, password = _) &
      // when the form is submitted, process the variable
      "type=submit" #> SHtml.onSubmitUnit(process)
  }
}
```

I dont have idea how to redirect to a view page from snippet in scala liftweb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is '/home' defined in your menu? If not, it won't be accessible and I believe you'll get that message.

On an unrelated but probably more important note: Are you aware of the significant issues with this approach to password management and authentication?

Comment: No '/home' is not defined in my menu. I just defined it in menu and that just worked. Thank you
Also i am not aware of the significant issues can you please highlight the issues....

Comment: You are storing the password in plaintext and any user can log in with any other user's password. Also, what is stopping a user from just going directly to /home? You should probably just use one of the templates based on ProtoUser and go from there - https://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Getting_Started (there are now 2.6 templates as well, but they are not mentioned on that page).

Comment: Hmmm, I take back the second part. Had missed the restriction by username. Regardless, storing passwords in plaintext is not good. The 2.6 version ProtoUser I believe uses bcrypt to store hashes of password values, which is a good practice. Cheers.